# How to optimize data that has two variables with leastsq in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, scikit-learn

I have [data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwwhEMUIYGyTQXdVR2dvLXhfZnc) of the form given below:

```
X   Y1  Y2  Y3  Y4  Y5  Y6
1.42857 4.83    4.58    4.43    4.31    4.22    4.14
1.40845 3.87    3.63    3.49    3.38    3.3 3.23
1.38889 3.17    2.93    2.79    2.69    2.62    2.56
1.36986 2.65    2.41    2.27    2.17    2.11    2.05
1.35135 2.27    2.02    1.88    1.78    1.72    1.67
    :     :       :       :       :        :      :
1.01010 2.26    1.6 1.21    0.97    0.79    0.66
1.00000 2.01    1.44    1.1 0.88    0.73    0.62
```

I am trying to optimize a function of the form:

[image]
[image]

Now my y variable has 6 columns, I can optimize one column (in MWE #3) which I have done in the MWE. How can I optimize the function to get the parameters A, n and B for all the 6 column values? In other words how can I get the value one value of A, n and B for all 6 values of y.

**MWE**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
import scipy.interpolate
from scipy.optimize import leastsq


with open('./exp_fit.dat', "r") as data:
    while True:
        line = data.readline()
        if not line.startswith('#'):
            break
    data_header = [i for i in line.strip().split('\t') if i]
    _data_ = np.genfromtxt(data, names = data_header, dtype = None, delimiter = '\t')
_data_.dtype.names = [j.replace('_', ' ') for j in _data_.dtype.names]
data = np.array(_data_.tolist())

x = _data_['X']
x_interp = np.linspace(x[-1], x[0], 100)

y = np.zeros(shape = (len(x), 6))
y_interp = np.zeros(shape = (len(x_interp), 6))
for i in range(6):
    y[:, i] = data[:, i + 1]
    tck = scipy.interpolate.splrep(x[::-1], y[::-1, i], s=0)
    y_interp[::-1, i] = scipy.interpolate.splev(x_interp, tck, der = 0)


def residuals(p, y, x):
    A_lt, n_lt, B_lt, A_it, n_it, B_it, A_ht, n_ht, B_ht = p
    err = y - (1 / (1 / ((A_it * (15 ** (-n_it)) * np.exp(B_it * x / 1000)) + \
        (A_lt * (15 ** (-n_lt)) * np.exp(B_lt * x / 1000))) + \
        1 / (A_ht * (15 ** (-n_ht)) * np.exp(B_ht * x / 1000))))
    return err
p1 = [2.789E-05, 1.47, 9.368E+03, 2.789E-05, 1.47, 9.368E+03, 2.789E-05, 1.47, 9.368E+03]
plsq = leastsq(residuals, p1, args=(y_interp[:, 2], x_interp))
A1, n1, B1, A2, n2, B2, A3, n3, B3 =  plsq[0]
```

Comment: Your residuals function should simply return the residuals over all the different columns. Also I'm not sure why you fit the interpolated function instead of the raw data. The latter seems the more standard way to go.

Comment: Will that provide a 2D optimization?

Comment: That will provide one set of parameters that best fits the overall data. Not sure what you mean by 2D optimization.